# Why a polynomial is irreducible over Z

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Prove that the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$:

$$f(x) = x^8-x^7+x^5-x^4+x^3-x+1$$

My attempt: one can see that $f(x)=(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x+1) $ over $\mathbb{F_2}$ where these 2 polynomials are irreducible, so if $f$ is factorizable, then

$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)$$ for $g,h\in\mathbb{Z[x]}$ - of degree 4.

I tried comparing coefficients, but it turned out to be extremely tedious. Another approach is to plug some fancy numbers into $f(x)$: I found that $f(x)-1 $ is divisible by $x\cdot(x+1)\cdot(x-1)\cdot(x^2+1)$, so $g(n)=1$ or $-1 $ for $n=-1,0,1$, but there are also too many cases. Now I have no idea how tackle it.

Comment: It turns out that this is the 15th cyclotomic polynomial, hence it is irreducible by definition.

Comment: For any composite $n,$ it is generally difficult to see that $\Phi_n(x)$ (i.e., the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial) is irreducible; however, here is a [link with a proof](https://www.lehigh.edu/~shw2/c-poly/several_proofs.pdf). (Check the top of page 6.)

Comment: For this particular problem: note that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $(\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z)[x]$. This implies its irreducibility in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @WhatsUp, why is this true? I know that it's true for $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ for prime $p,$ but does it extend to prime powers?

Comment: If you have a factorization in $\Bbb Z[x]$, then modulo $9$ gives you a factorization in $(\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z)[x]$.

Comment: Great idea! I suppose it can also be done using modulo 3 as well: comparing coefficients and doing some case works, this problem comes down to around 16-24 cases of just multiplying. Or perhaps I am missing something and your mod 9 solution involves no/ less case works?

Comment: It turns out to be true that if $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x],$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ if it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_n[x]$ for any integer $n \geq 2,$ but the argument requires a bit more care than what @Whatsup suggests.

Comment: @Afar Yes, what I wanted to say is that this comes down to finitely many cases. I don't know whether there are further tricks to reduce the number of cases, but I suppose these would be quite specialized to this problem, if any. Note but mod $3$ the polynomial is actually reducible: it is $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)^2$. This however gives information about the mod $9$ factorization, which helps with reducing cases.